# Need proper array calculation for this function

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, function, loops

Here is my requirement of algorithm to find donater id which sum of donation
is equal to required donation

```
<?php

function magicalFunction($donationArray , $expactedValue ){
    /*need some algorithm get key of elements from $donationArray which sum is   
    equal to $expactedValue  $*/
}

$userDonation = array(
    '1' => 100,
    '4' => 8064,
    '5' => 578,
    '6' => 752,
    '21' => 512,
    '121' => 660,
    '152' => 135,
    '199' => 1350
);

$requiredDonation = 886;
$selectedDonatee = magicalFunction( $userDonation , $requiredDonatee ); 
// return false

$requiredDonation = 1465;
$selectedDonatee = magicalFunction( $userDonation , $requiredDonatee ); 
// return array(5, 6, 152);

?>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want, can you give me an example using your own array?

Comment: I can almost guarantee there's a much better way to accomplish whatever it is you're doing. You want to sum array values to equal the int passed to the function correct?

Comment: So, have you tried anything yourself, or is this just a requirement spec. where you expect us to just build it for you?

Comment: Updated formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. This will be slow with larger input arrays, but it works in theory. Also, this will return the first combination of keys with values that sum to the target value that it finds, and any other possible combinations will be ignored.

```
function findSet($values, $target, $keys = [], $sum = 0) {

    while ($k = key($values)) {
        $v = reset($values);

        // return the current set of keys if the target sum is found
        if ($sum + $v == $target) return array_merge($keys, [$k]);

        // remove the current value
        unset($values[$k]);

        // recursively test the remaining values and return if a matching set is found
        if ($sum + $v < $target) {
            $test = findSet($values, $target, array_merge($keys, [$k]), $sum + $v);
            if ($test) return $test;
        }
    }

    // return false if no matching sets are found
    return false;
}

$result = findSet($userDonation, 1465);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Subset Sum Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and it is [NP-Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).

> ... given a set of integers and an integer s, does any non-empty subset sum to s? ...

Here:

- **$requiredDonation** is the **s**
- **$userDonation** is the **set of integers**
- **magicalFunction** returns the subset of the **set of integers** that sum to **s**. (A non-false answer is the true of the *proper* NP-Complete question and the false is the false)

The [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) provides some solutions for subset sum problems and google search others.

- [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.02318.pdf) is one recomendation.
- [Here](https://github.com/burento/Subset-Sum-Problem/blob/master/subset.php) is PHP based solver.

You may also wish to evaluate the requirements, as the problem may get out of hand if the number of donations to search is large. (This is a property of NP-Complete problems. They can take a long time to solve exactly).